# How can I debug what targets a given NuGet package?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, twilio, twilio-api, callkit

I'm trying to install [Twilio Voice for Xamarin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twilio.Voice.Xamarin/), and when I try to add it to my app, I get this error:

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Twilio.Voice.Xamarin.2.0.0-beta4-1' with respect to project 'voipphone', targeting 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0'
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/twilio.voice.xamarin/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration1-gz/twilio.voice.xamarin/index.json 169ms
Total number of results gathered : 5
Gathering dependency information took 705.89 ms
Summary of time taken to gather dependencies per source :
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -   171.21 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Twilio.Voice.Xamarin.2.0.0-beta4-1' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'Twilio.Voice.Xamarin.2.0.0-beta4-1'
Resolved actions to install package 'Twilio.Voice.Xamarin.2.0.0-beta4-1'
Retrieving package 'Twilio.Voice.Xamarin 2.0.0-beta4-1' from 'nuget.org'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Twilio.Voice.Xamarin.2.0.0-beta4-1' does not exist in project 'privatephone'
Package 'Twilio.Voice.Xamarin.2.0.0-beta4-1' does not exist in folder '/Users/Joe/Projects/voipapp/packages'
Executing nuget actions took 56.56 ms
Could not install package 'Twilio.Voice.Xamarin 2.0.0-beta4-1'. You are trying to 
  install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0',
  but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible 
  with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

**Question**

How can I manually download, inspect this NuGet package so I can see its intended use?

Comment: A question, what type of Xamarin.iOS proj do you have? VS2015 (with packages.config), VS2015/2017 with project.json or the new VS2017 csproj format?

Answer (score 0):

To download a Nuget Package, just go to this url: https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Twilio.Voice.Xamarin/2.0.0-beta4-1

Once you download it, you can use something like 7zip to extract it and see its contents.

Looking inside it, it is designed for Xamarin.iOS and Android and I successfully installed it in my Xamarin.iOS app.